# How to check if XML node exist or not

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I am trying to check if node "Key" is present in the XML, If not i have to assign "No Node" instead.
Below is the code i am using, but it throws me the error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in the line where i check nodevalue against Nothing.
How can i check if the XML node exist or not ?

```
           Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
            doc.Load(strPath)
            'Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces.
            Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("vvp", "http://schemas.abc.efg.IJ/zyx/")

            'Fetch nodes
            Dim MyRootNode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//vvp:provider", nsmgr)
            If (MyRootNode("Key").InnerXml <> Nothing) Then
               OrgCode = "No Node"
            End If
```

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? It's simpler in LINQ to XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have to use XMLDocument for some other reasons. How can i do this ?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't got the time to look at the old XmlDocument API right now - hopefully someone else will answer though.

Comment: Can you post some xml sample, as confused it is like so <vvp><key></key></vvp> or <vvp>key</vvp>

Comment: @abhinavpratap It is like <vvp><key></key></vvp>

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
Dim MyRootNode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//vvp:provider", nsmgr)
Dim keyNodelst As XmlNodeList=MyRootNode.SelectNodes(".//Key")
            If (!keyNodelst.Count>0) Then
               OrgCode = "No Node"
            End If
```

or

```
Dim MyRootNode As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//vvp:provider", nsmgr)
    Dim keyNode As XmlNode=MyRootNode.SelectSingleNode(".//Key")
                If (keyNode==null) Then
                   OrgCode = "No Node"
                End If
```

For xpath refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools (see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why). You might have linked to a page that contains correct information, but the site has a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to w3schools in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve. (If you use Google Search, and you have a Google account, you can [easily block results](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210386) from w3schools)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably if there is no key then `MyRootNode("Key")` is nothing which is why you get the null reference exception?

I'd have thought this simple modification should work:

```
If (MyRootNode("Key") is Nothing) Then
    OrgCode = "No Node"
End If
```

(ie we removed the attempt to get the inner XML).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectSingleNode method again to try to find your "Key" node. It does not exist in case your variable is Nothing.

Please refer to the following link for more information
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/d7cbb3d3-6c1a-48fd-a2ab-40b9910fe453